# Remove resize at the end of img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, image

I am trying to remove a string at the end of my img src for all my img elements on the page.

An example of an img src as it appears now

```
http://www.example.com/B-UV-image-copy.jpg?resize=320%2C180
```

How I want it to be

```
http://www.example.com/B-UV-image-copy.jpg
```

I am trying to use javascript in the footer to find all img elements then remove ?resize=320%2C180 from all of them. The string "?resize=320%2C180" is always the same on all the images I want to effect.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<script>
  $('img').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
  return attr.replace("?resize=320%2C180", "");
  });
</script>
```

I appreciate I may be going about this all wrong. Currently the above script does nothing but I get an error in firebug:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you waited for jQuery to be ready?

Comment: or placed your script at the end of the `body` element.

Comment: Can you set this up in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Moob - "I am trying to use javascript in the footer"

Comment: It's working here...http://jsfiddle.net/0vhj1umq/

Comment: [The code works](http://jsfiddle.net/w2ce2tb8/1/)

Comment: If your jquery is called properly, put the code in document ready and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You just need to [ensure that the DOM is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) before you ask jQuery it to manipulate it:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
        return attr.replace("?resize=320%2C180", "");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/os5rhw23/

Comment: You mean: "to ensure the DOM is ready" (jQuery is obviously loaded or the first `$` would fail) :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. You just need the DOM to be loaded and you need to make sure `$` is tied to `jQuery`.

```
<script>
   (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('img').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
            return attr.replace("?resize=320%2C180", "");
          });
       });
   }(window.jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery(function($){ your code here });` does both the DOM ready and the IEFE (to give a local $) in one compact shortcut version.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to be as explicit as possible and explain that actually both things need to happen in order for his code to work.

Comment: the IEFE is not needed in this instance. There is no indication of clashes with other plugins (which seldom happens on recent projects, mainly on legacy code).

Answer (score 1):

Using RegExp to strip off all the query part from a URL:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('img').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
        return attr.replace(/\?.*$/i, '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct, but the nicest shorthand for a DOM ready handler *and* a locally scoped `$` for jQuery is `jQuery(function ($) { your code here}`:

e.g.

```
<script>
   jQuery(function ($) {
       $('img').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
          return attr.replace("?resize=320%2C180", "");
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with pure JS, inline in the footer without the need for jQuery you can simply loop through all images - so long as this script in on the page at some point *after* the images (eg just before the close body)

```
<body>
    <!-- some html, blah blah -->
    <script>
        var images = document.images,
            i = images.length;
        while(i--) {
            var image = images[i];
            image.src = image.src.replace("?resize=320%2C180", "");
        }
    <script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/os5rhw23/1/